# Trouble Installing SoX

Tags: macos, sox

I am running Mac OSX 10.8.4 and am unable to install SoX. I have almost 0 knowledge of UNIX or terminal but require SoX for an audio job. I have downloaded Sox-14.4.1 from the site. I attempt to launch the exec (sox.exec) but get the error:

"/Users/home/sox-14.4.1/sox FAIL sox: Not enough input filenames specified"

I have attempted to find help on this but have been unable to find any solutions. I've tried installing Xcode and all the suggestions that go along with that.

Comment: Welcome to Superuser, when asking a question please use a question mark as to clearly show what you're asking. If you would like more information on how to ask good question please see [ask]

Comment: Have you tried specifying an input filename for `sox`? Clearly you want to work on some kind of audio file with it.

Comment: But don't I first need to install sox? The application I am wanting to run requires SoX to be installed then you run the application (split2mono.sh in this case) and it works it's magic. But I get the error 'soxi command not found' when I attempt to run split2mono

Answer (score 0):

I am also a new SoX user and I usually get the "Not enough input filenames specified" error when I enter a SoX command incorrectly. It sounds like you may already have SoX installed but aren't specifying an input as slhck mentioned.

However, if you are really unsure if SoX is installed, you can try going through Homebrew, which is what I did.

In terminal:

- Install [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/)
- Entered `brew install sox`
- SoX will take a few moments to install.

I am also relatively inexperienced with Terminal, but I think Homebrew will give you a "sox is already installed" warning if the program exists in /usr/bin. I'm certain someone more knowledgable than I will be able to correct any errors in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the SoX in the terminal with commands like for example

```
sox music.aif music.ogg
```

Your question indicates that you might either be trying to use SoX as an app with a graphical user interface or that you are not passing file names as parameters in the command line. It does seem that SoX is installed on your system though.

`sox` is a command-line tool and has no graphical interface. To test `sox`:

1. Start the Terminal (Navigate to /Applications/Utilities and press the Terminal app icon).
2. Put an audio file into your *home* folder, for example `music.aif`
3. Run `sox music.aif music.ogg` (type the text into the terminal and press enter to run it)
4. After a short while, you should have an OGG Vorbis version of the music file in your home directory.

You will need to use the command line (terminal) or you can use the free [SoX-Wrap](http://www.waveformsoftware.com/waveform/sox_wrap) tool if converting audio files is what you want to use sox for.